# Reg not starting vbscript

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, registry

I've got registry entries inside of a .reg file. The reg file is for making a URI Scheme. It worked when I was passing %1 argument to a .bat file, but I don't like viewing the .bat file, so I want to use the well known VBScript method of hiding the .bat file. How do I pass the arguments to the batch file?

Apps.reg

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Apps]
@="URL:Apps Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Apps\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Apps\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Apps\shell\open\command]
@="\"M:\\Apps\\Apps.vbs\" \"%1\""
```

Apps.vbs

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Apps.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The batch file just uses %1 argument. The problem is getting the argument to the batch file. Currently every time I try to use the URI Scheme with the VBScript, I get "apps://foo is not a valid Win32 application." Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
WshShell.Run "Apps.bat /foo", 0
```

If you want to separate your program path which may include spaces from the command line you could try this:

```
WshShell.Run """Apps.bat"" /foo", 0
```